# How can I make instance-Z2.log register the actual usernames?

Tags: plone

I have a plain Plone 4 configuration and I need to keep track of users' activity. However, the log file instance-Z2.log labels all accesses to the server as "Anonymous" or "admin". I.e., regular users are labelled as Anonymous, therefore I can't extract any stats about individual users' activity.

How can I change that behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used it myself, but I believe this is what http://plone.org/products/collective.usernamelogger does.  Give it a whirl. :-)